# Android Geoloqi SDK: getting group/create api call to work

Tags: android, api, request, token

I'm coding a project using the Geoloqi android sdk. I want to use the api method call group/create, but in my OnRunApiRequestListener() inner class, onComplete() keeps returning instead of onSuccess(). The error code that I find in logcat is "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". I looked it up on geoloqi's website and the error code said that "Auth token found in GET or POST when token present in header". Not entirely sure what this means, but I think it has something to do with the fact that group/create requires an application access token. I have an application access token, but I don't know where to put it in my project. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you tell me a little about what you are trying to do with your app?

It's not recommended to put the application access token in a client-side app, because it is relatively easy to extract strings out of APKs and the application access token allows admin access to your app.

A possible solution would be to create a simple server that receives requests from your android app and makes requests to Geoloqi on the app's behalf.

Comment: The app we are making basically acts as a minimap heads up display for a real life multiplayer tagging game (humans vs zombies) which has two teams. The main function of our app is to show the user the gps position of the players on their team relative to their current position and not those of users on the other team (users choose their team when first starting the app). So right now we are trying to create the groups to represent the two teams and we are just having trouble getting the api request call for the groups to work.

Comment: In that case, you can exchange your client credentials for an application token and then instantiate a new LQSession to make requests with.